# Reuse a IAsyncEnumerable instance without having to iterate again

Tags: c#, asynchronous, task-parallel-library, ienumerable, iasyncenumerable

I am currently writing a method like this:

```
public async Task<UserModel> GetUserByUserIdAsync(string userId)
{
    IQueryable<UserEntity> usersQuery = BuildQueryable(userId);

    bool any = await usersQuery.ExecuteQuery().AnyAsync();
    
    if (!any) return null; // wanna do other logic in the future

    return (await usersQuery.ExecuteQuery().SingleAsync()).ToUserModel();
}
```

As you can see, I am calling the `await usersQuery.ExecuteQuery()` twice, and `ExecuteQuery()` is a method which iterates my database and could be considered an expensive operation. Is there any way I could save my `IAsyncEnumerable<T>` like I normally would with `IEnumerable<T>` and re-use it throughout my code?

I thought about using `ToListAsync()` on it, but I am unsure whether that is considered good practice or not. I've also read that I could return a `Task<IAsyncEnumerable<T>>` and do something with that maybe. What is the best way to handle this? I'd like to implement the most efficient solution.

Comment: How about writing the foreach yourself, that way you can iterate once and handle all contingencies yourself?

Comment: "like I normally would with IEnumerable<T> and re-use it throughout my code?" You know that the same applies to `IEnumerable<T>` as well? Iterating the same `IEnumerable<T>` again *will* of course fetch the underlying datastore again as well. You have to materialize the result somehow, I´d go with `ToListAsync`.

Comment: @HimBromBeere Well, yes, but not in this context I believe. If my `ExecuteQuery()` returns a `Task<List<T>>`, I could save the list in my other method, such as `var dbResponse = ExecuteQuery();` and then I could work with dbResponse throughout the method without making multiple trips to the database.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen What do you mean by writing the foreach myself? Do you mean the foreach inside the `ExecuteQuery()` method? If so, that one is supposed to read all elements for the given query. You are suggesting that I should handle these cases in that method there?

Comment: You would access DB, at least once, in any case, so just do `(await usersQuery.ExecuteQuery().FirstOrDefaultAsync()).ToUserModel()` and compare it with `null` for specific logic

Comment: You can use `SingleOrDefaultAsync`. Either it will return 1 or null record. With that you don't need to make two calls for `any` and `single`

Comment: No, inside the `GetUserByUserIdAsync` method, in the method you posted in the question. But as others have mentioned, since you're only going to use the first item anyway you should be using `FirstOrDefaultAsync` or a similar method.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen I did have a foreach loop initially, but I wasn't sure how to check whether there are any items in the list or not. `await foreach (var item in usersQuery.ExecuteQuery()) {}` It would enter inside the loop whether there are elements or not, which is why I started looking for another solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not simply use [SingleOrDefaultAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.queryableextensions.singleordefaultasync?view=entity-framework-6.2.0)? Assuming your entity is a reference type you can get your single item, check if it is null to handle the empty-case. Another alternative is always to convert the [enumerable to a list](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.queryableextensions.tolistasync?view=entity-framework-6.2.0). Then you can iterate over it however many times you want to.

Comment: I think you are correct, I was overthinking it a little bit. I was thinking if I had to re-use the list multiple times, how would I handle it in the future, but if that's the case, I could just convert it to a normal List and work with it. Are there any downsides to converting `IAsyncEnumerable<T>` to `List<T>`? Also, I'm not using EF Core in my case.

Comment: @axajkamkat you would need to have all items in memory. If this is a problem or not depends on the use case. Often pagination is used to limit the amount of items returned.

Comment: Fair enough. A very useful library for these things is https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Linq.Async (fairly new and less documentation). I could use the `ToListAsync()` to make a `List<T>` out of the `IAsyncEnumerable<T>` with the extension methods from that library.

Comment: I would advice against the `ToListAsync`, because the OP is interested only for the first element of the asynchronous sequence. Awaiting for all elements could result to a waste of time and resources.

Answer (score 1):

In case there is any possibility for the single returned `UserEntity` to be `null`, and you want to differentiate between no-entity and one-null-entity, you could install the [System.Linq.Async](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Linq.Async) package and do this:

```
public async Task<UserModel> GetUserByUserIdAsync(string userId)
{
    IQueryable<UserEntity> usersQuery = BuildQueryable(userId);

    var (userEntity, exists) = await usersQuery
        .AsAsyncEnumerable()
        .Select(x => (x, true))
        .FirstOrDefaultAsync();

    if (!exists) return null; // wanna do other logic in the future
    return userEntity.ToUserModel();
}
```

This query exploits the fact that the default value of a [`ValueTuple<UserEntity, bool>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.valuetuple-2) is `(null, false)`.

Using the [`AsAsyncEnumerable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.entityframeworkqueryableextensions.asasyncenumerable) may not be as efficient as using the [`SingleOrDefaultAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.entityframeworkqueryableextensions.singleordefaultasync) method though, because the data provider may create a less optimized execution plan.